# DataFrame time interval extrapolation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, date-range

I have a `DataFrame` given with a 10 minute interval which looks likes this:

```
    intervall_start         group   count
0   2014-03-05 14:30:00     A       2
1   2014-03-05 14:40:00     A       2
2   2014-03-05 14:50:00     B       2
3   2014-03-05 15:00:00     B       1
4   2014-03-05 15:10:00     A       4
5   2014-03-05 15:20:00     B       1
```

My goal is now to extrapolate this 10 minute interval into a 15 minute, 30 minute or 1 hour interval. I want to set the interval in which the 10 minute interval should be extrapolated. So it should be dynamically!

Let's say I want to extrapolate the 10 minute interval into a 15 minute interval then I want to have this result.

```
    intervall_start         group   count
0   2014-03-05 14:30:00     A       (10/15 * 2 + 5/15 * 2) = 2
1   2014-03-05 14:45:00     A       (5/15 * 2 + 10/15 * 0) = 0.666
2   2014-03-05 15:00:00     A       (10/15 * 4 + 5/15 * 0) = 2.666
3   2014-03-05 15:15:00     A       (5/15 * 4 + 10/15 * 1) = 2

    intervall_start         group   count
0   2014-03-05 14:45:00     B       (5/15 * 0 + 10/15 * 2) = 1.333
1   2014-03-05 15:00:00     B       (10/15 * 1 + 5/15 * 0) = 0.666
2   2014-03-05 15:15:00     B       (5/15 * 0 + 10/15 * 1) = 0.666
```

Do you guys have any idea how to do that? But as I said, dynamically! I also want to be able to shift it into a 5 minute or 1 hour interval!

Why I use `10/15` and `5/15` as weights? Because this is the weight for the 15 minute interval. For exmaple if I have 3 counts from 15:00 to 15:10 then this is a `10/15 * 3` weight!

**Explanation of count:**

I count in my database if the gate for the group was open or closed. 1 is opened and 0 is closed. I just select the gates which are opened (1) and count them. So, I know how many gates were opened for this group!

Now I am not allowed to sum those counts up! Because otherwise I would have more gates opened then I actually have! I have to calculate the average of gates which were opened for the timeframe!

Kind regards and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is `resample`:

```
# Create a date-time index
df.intervall_start = pd.to_datetime(df.intervall_start)
df.set_index("intervall_start", inplace = True)

# make sure we have a sample every 10 minutes (fill missing samples with 0)
df = df.groupby("group")[["count"]].resample("10min").asfreq()
df = df.fillna(0)

# sample every minute, to be later used when calculatiung the mean per period
df = df.reset_index(level = "group").groupby("group")[["count"]].resample("1min").pad()

# resample for every 15 minutes using 'mean'
df = df.reset_index(level = "group").groupby("group")[["count"]].resample("15min").mean()
```

The output is:

```
                              count
group intervall_start              
A     2014-03-05 14:30:00  2.000000
      2014-03-05 14:45:00  0.666667
      2014-03-05 15:00:00  0.363636
B     2014-03-05 14:45:00  2.000000
      2014-03-05 15:00:00  0.666667
      2014-03-05 15:15:00  0.166667
```

Comment: I get `Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'` as error

Comment: Got it. I thought it's already a date-index. Added the relevant code to make it so.

Comment: Thats close to what I want. The problem now is that The count is wrong! It should not sum up it should calulate the count in average!

Comment: Emm. It seems like the sum of the count in the output is the same as in the input - at least for the example in the question. Isn't it?

Comment: Oh sorry... my fault. Yes, the sum is the same, but I described it wrong! The count should not be summed up it should be calculated the average. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Sorry. I don’t understand. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have added Explanation of count above in my question!

Comment: I’m still not sure I follow. If you had 5 samples of counts 1-2-3-4-5, and you’re now resembling to only two time stamps - what should be the result and why?

Comment: Give me some time, I will make an better example!

Comment: I do now know what I need and want! I want to have the weighted mean. I will give you an example above!

Comment: Yes, perfectly! Thank You!